# problem with jquery animate function help

Tags: jquery, animation

I had developed a small animation using jquery. But my problem is when i am animating a div using flowing script

```
$('#square').animate({left: -350+"px"},'slow');
```

it is working great..
But when i am replacing **left** with **right** animation is not working

```
$('#square').animate({right: -350+"px"},'slow');
```

The above is not animating any..

what might be the problem?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it might very well be that you always use `left`. So, use `left: '350px'` instead of `right: '-350px'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the positive of left.

```
$('#square').animate({left: "=350px"},'slow');
```

my bad, try that